# Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode

Tags: android-intent

I'am getting a error "Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode".
The following is the case:
I'am starting an intent like this

```
startActivityForResult(i, R.integer.intent_someName);
```

So basiclly passing a kind of constant as the requestCode.
I have put in 'constant' in my resources like this:

```
<integer name="intent_someName">100</integer>
```

Now i have seen more post's where the problem is a negative number or a number above the 32655 (or something close to that). Both of those are not the case. So why the error?
if i put this in my code it works:

```
int test = 100;
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, someNameActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, test);
```

I seems that an Integer in the resouces is something else as an int why????
I'am lost.
And yes, i could simply hardcode the int-value but that would be missing the point.

any inside in solving would be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
startActivityForResult(i, R.integer.intent_someName);
```

to:

```
startActivityForResult(i, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.intent_someName));
```

The reason for the original error is that you've directly referenced R.integer, as opposed to using getResources() to get the integer value from the integer.xml file.

Hope that this helps!

Answer (score 0):

in the end i solved this by creating a abstract class.
The class holds al constants in the shape of "public static final ...."

Maybe not the best option but it works great